# Bar Graphs: Fixing the visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import education
list_of_record = education.get_all_states()
virginia_education = education.get_state('Virginia')

attendance = virginia_education["attendance"]

if "attendance" in virginia_education:
    student_rate = attendance ["average student rate"]
    teacher_rate = attendance ["average teacher rate"]

rates = [student_rate, teacher_rate]

x = rates

plt.bar (1,student_rate)
plt.bar (2,teacher_rate)
plt.title ('Average Student Rate Attendence vs. Average Teacher Rate    Attendence in Virginia')
plt.show ()
```

[image: Current graph]

I would like the x-axis to just be labeled as "student rate" and "teacher rate". I know how to label the x-axis but I do not know how to change the 1, 1.2, 1.2 etc.

```
plt.bar (1,student_rate)
plt.bar (2,teacher_rate)
```

What do I change to fix this?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html might be a good reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to matplotlib website:
http://matplotlib.org/examples/ticks_and_spines/ticklabels_demo_rotation.html

you can create a labels array:

```
labels = ["student rate", "teacher rate"]
```

then modify the x ticks:

```
plt.xticks(x, labels)
```